# Change Navigation Bar Tint Color while presenting new view controller modally in iOS 4.x

Tags: ios4, presentmodalviewcontroller, email-client, navigationbar, tintcolor

In my view controller's I have following code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:201.0/255.0 green:201.0/255.0 blue:201.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

On this view when I click a button , I am presenting `MFMailComposeViewController` modally. When I present `MFMailComposeViewController` modally, navigation bar same color as set in `viewWillAppear`. I want default blue color as Apple told that don't customize this view. Here is my code which I have tried

Code 1:

```
-(void)sendEmailWithWithRecipients:(NSArray*)recipients andData:(NSData*)data {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 

        mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;
        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES];
        [mailComposeViewController release]; 
    }  
    else {
        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Alert" andMessage:@"Can not send email. Please check your email settings."];
    }
}
```

But above code is not working for tint color

Code 2: Set tint color in `viewWillDisappear`

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Code 2 also not working.

But this is working fine in iOS5 **without** setting `tintColor = nil` while presenting `MFMailComposeViewController` modally & in `viewWillDisappear`. Its not working iOS 4.x

Anyone have solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: You dont want to change only tintColor or whole background color of your navigation bar

Comment: @R.A I want default navigation bar when I present mailComposeViewController modally

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the navigationbar's tint color by accessing **yourController**'s(ViewController which you are presetnting) **topViewController**.

Ex :

```
[self presentModalViewController:yourController animated:YES];
yourController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = 
    [UIColor (Your Color)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the navigation bar style rather than the tint color.  Tint color and bar style have slightly different side effects, so while I don't completely understand your needs, it might be exactly what you're looking for.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
```

or

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
```

And make sure you do this within the context of the modal view controller, not the previous view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nil try this `[UIColor ClearColor];`

Comment: Set tintcolor in viewdidload method instead of viewwillappear.

Comment: [[mailComposeViewController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];Try this.

Comment: [[mailComposeViewController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; changing bar buttons color but navigation bar color remains same